# stdio.h function fopen() error scenarios in "w" mode

Tags: c, file, error-handling, null, fopen

I have experimented with fopen() in writing mode to try and see if it ever returns NULL. I tried opening multiple files of the same name, and inputting invalid file names. Obviously, fopen() does not care about recycled names, as it just opens a fresh file every time and overwrites any existing data. Inputting invalid file names merely caused a command line error. None of the test cases I tried caused fopen() to return NULL.

This is never something that I have encountered in everyday programming, but I always follow the philosophy of never assuming that a file will always be successfully opened. Thus, I always error-check every file pointer, regardless of what I am doing with the file.

But for full awareness about file I/O, I found myself curious: What are the scenarios, if any, in which fopen() will return NULL in "w" mode?

Answer (score 1):

Try opening a file in a directory that doesn't exist, or one that you have no permissions to overwrite, or one with invalid characters in the file name.  You'll get NULL pretty quickly in those situations.

Your philosophy is a good one by the way, it's generally a good idea to check *any* call that can fail. There are, of course, exceptions to the rule, I don't check the return value of every `printf` call but that's usually because it's unlikely to bite me later on in the program.

Comment: I hadn't thought of that. Permissions especially. Thank you. As for invalid characters in the file name, in what instance could this occur? I tried doing it with invalid characters, but it just lead to a bash error.

Comment: There are likely characters you can put into strings in C that `bash` may not allow directly. Try using `*` or `:` under NTFS, for example. But, to be honest, permissions/no-directory are proabably the big ones.